# How do i do a 301 redirect to a specific location

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to remove the slash of 1 and only 1 url

this snippet will remove them all

```
# Remove the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but i just want to change

```
example.com/changeme/
```

to

```
example.com/changeme
```

any ideas how to change this htaccess i have to only do it on one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `(.+)` with `(changeme)` in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(changeme)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will only match 'changeme' and not everything.

In this way you can also match multiple URLs, including e.g. 'changeother' and 'foobar':

```
RewriteRule ^(changeme|changeother|foobar)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
RewriteRule ^changeme/$ http://www.example.com/changeme [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is (as long as this rewrite is only applied to example.com):

```
RewriteRule ^changeme/$ changeme [R=301,L]
```

Comment: whats the difference between ^(.+/changeme) and ^(changeme)

Comment: Thanks for your question I've just realised my answer can't be correct, so I'm updating it.